# Check if Recycle Bin is corrupted with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, recycle-bin

On Windows, if the Recycle Bin is corrupted, a prompt similar to the image below is shown in the Windows GUI:

[image: Recycle Bin Corrupted Error]

I'd like to automate a check for this using PowerShell. How can I check if the recycle bin under a mountpoint (whether it's a directory mount or letter drive) is corrupted? The only cmdlet I've found in PowerShell relating to the recycle bin is `Clear-RecycleBin`. I've also looked at how to perform this from C# and only found methods to `P/Invoke` to the `Win32` API to clear the recycle bin, but nothing on how to check the recycle bin's integrity programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this works for you:

```
$bin = 'C:\$Recycle.Bin'
try {
    $items = Get-ChildItem -Path $bin -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Host "$bin seems just fine. Contains $($items.Count) items." -ForegroundColor Green
}
catch {
    Write-Host "$bin looks corrupted.." -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this was the first thing I tried. Gci doesn't return anything under the recycle bin directory, and doesn't error out.